# navbar-toggle causing button to left align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wrote a [mobile menu button](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/) which works fine until I add class "navbar-toggle" to it. After adding the class, the button gets left aligned.

```
        <button  type="button" class="col-xs-12 btn btn-success  collapsed navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#primary-menu"  aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'child-life-foundation' ); ?></button>
        <nav class="navbar  " role="navigation" id="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu', 'menu_class'      => 'nav' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

Comment: Don't mix `col-*-*` classes with anything else. Use containers for layout and put your content in those. Bootstrap is not **magic**. It's only CSS. If you put all the Bootstrap classes on a single element it will not do much, if anything. Markup and structure are very important. Don't use `col-xs-12` and `navbar-toggle` on the same element. They both affect the `display` property of that element, contradicting.

Comment: My advice to people without a strong experience and understanding of CSS: when using Bootstrap, always COPY their working examples in your code and modify those. There are a lot of "not so obvious" aspects about it that most people often overlook.